# Is there a 3D mesh file format that allows for dynamic parameters?

Tags: 3d, file-format

Suppose I want to be able to show 3D models of an object in a 3D program, but the shape of this mesh is governed by a number of parameters (a, b, c..) such that an instance can have any of several thousand possible combinations.

Imagine for example a library of bolts, where the basic shape of a bolt could easily be drawn in a standard CAD program for *one* specific instance of a bolt (a certain length, diameter, head diameter), but rather than having to create thousands of nearly equal model files for all permutations I'd like to create the meshes as "dynamic" or "parametric". Note that a simple scale of the entire model or even a part of the model will not be enough. Individual vertices will have to basically have dynamic positions `(x,y,z) = f(a, b, c)`

The solution to this problem probably requires both a file format (to encode the dynamic template model into a file) and some code to apply the parameters and get the final model. I know AutoCad has what is known as "dynamic blocks", but I don't know if they could be parsed and used in a standalone application.

The only solution I have come up with so far is to draw the model in a standard CAD format, in a normalized coordinate system with integer coordinates so that various planes of the model line up with known coordinates, and then I'd code a mapping so that e.g. any coordinate (x,y,3)  would be mapped to `(x,y,a)` for example. This is fairly limited in that it only allows for mapping of planar sections, and the model itself would consist of both the file *and* set of external hard coded mappings for that file.

The model needs to be aquired explicitly, i.e. I can't use "implicit" transforms such as using a skeleton and vertex shader in the visuzalization step only, since I need to be able to save the final transformed mesh.

The visualization will be done using Direct3D9, the code is C#/.NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

This is how modern parametric CAD software work. Most notably the applications that you're after are Solidworks, Creo (Pro|engineer), Catia, NX. Possibly Inventor also. Auto-CAD is very rudimentary in this sense its only 30 years behind the current state of the art. I have seen Pro|engineer models that build entire 90% final designs of oil rigs with all relevant calculation and simulation. So all of these natively do what you ask. The bolt example is very simple in terms of what I do daily in complexity. Indeed any of my students could have done this after the first exercise with no problems.

Now the relevant format is called SETP ap 214. however there's not much anything that actually supports this format fully (the standard for the format is about 5000 pages long). As it requires a very powerful 3D engine to resolve so basically one of the above software.

**EDIT:**

However if your models are polygon models **for games** its actually rather trivial to do what you want, just not very user friendly. Just export your parametrization as joint data and move/scale the joints most DCC formats have this capability. But please note games graphics has nothing to do with CAD. or cad formats. They have different software for this., such as 3dsMax or Maya. Most formats in this category support joints. You could add some extensions for joint movement rules for parametrization if formats such as collada. Depends a but on how you want to parametrize this. Ill have to test this myself, but since it works in Maya i see no reason why it would not work in a format.

Problem is hat games aren't exactly one platform.

Comment: I am creating software where I need to *display* these models. I can use e.g. Solidworks to *create* models, but it feels like it doesn't solve the entire problem (unless e.g. STEP has a very simple way of describing parametric triangle meshes). The software I'm creating isn't (and won't be) a full parametric cad package of course. Consider e.g. if someone wanted some parametric reusable triagle mesh blocks in a game. That is the scenario here.

Comment: Step does not deal in polygons. In this case is suggest you go and contact http://www.coretechnologie.de/PRODUCT_SUITE And get kernel_IO However there really is no such format as this. Its trivial to roll your own tough.

Comment: On second tought COLLADA might be able to do this with a extension.

Comment: Its not going into a game engine, nor a cad engine. Its a simple visualization basically. I know some STEP formats allow triangle mesh boundary reps (for example the IFC format). Its possible that some extension of IFC or COLLADA can allow a parametrization of a triangle mesh, I will look into that. The thought crossed my mind to use bones/skinning to create the deformation, but I don't know if it is trivial to apply the bone weights myself to the meshes (i.e. not just do it via vertex shaders but as "real" transformations)?

Comment: It is trivial to apply weighted movements yourself they are after all just weighted sums of vectors. I think that you should modify your question to be a bit better in line what you want. Then we can rewrite the answer together to suit your spirit. WHat platform are you targeting the visualization eg is it opengl, webgl, and existing application or something else. Anyway vertex shaders but are "real" transformations.

Comment: Yes they are real transformations, but usually you don't apply them yourself but simply feed them into a vertex shader that applies them. I agree that it does seem simple to apply the transforms manually too. I don't know how easy it would be to author something like a bolt model with bones though... I'll update the question although platform not really important, since I need to code it by hand and aquire the end result mesh explicitly regardless of the visualization (e.g. for saving).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26357/discussion-between-joojaa-and-anders-forsgren)